# blinking movieclip with timer

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i am trying to make my movieclip blink, it blinks when it is hit by something, to create the effect of a game.i have a hit test when it is hitted, caught is called on the object.the caught function of the object will make it stop and start to blink based on a timer.My timer is set on new Timer(400); why does my object not blink? my conditions seem to be correct.

```
if (hit.hitTestObject(f.hit))
    f.caught();


    private function blinkingHandler(evt:TimerEvent):void
    {

        _canBlink = true;
        if (_canBlink)
        {
            this.alpha = 0;
            _canBlink = false;
            this.alpha = 100;
            trace("blinking");
        }
    }
    public function caught() : void
    {   
        _blinkTimer.start();


        //removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

        //this.stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm going to assume that you have added the event listener to trigger the `blinkingHandler` call when the Timer fires:

```
_blinkTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, blinkingHandler);
```

Now, `blinkingHandler` as you have posted it will never hide the object. The alpha is set to 0, but you immediately set it back to 1 in the same call, so the net result is that the alpha does not display at 0. You must set the alpha to 0, let a few frames render, set it back to 1 on the next timer tick, and so on. Try this:

```
private function blinkingHandler(evt:TimerEvent):void
{
    if(_canBlink) this.alpha = 1;
    else this.alpha = 0;
    _canBlink = !_canBlink;
}
```

You could even do:

```
visible = !visible;
```

To simply toggle the visibility on each timer tick.

Comment: Also, while it still works as 100, for AS3, the alpha value range is 0-1.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer:Timer =  new Timer(200);
var blink:Boolean = true;
timer.start();
sq_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMseOvrAction);
sq_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onMseOutAction);
function onMseOvrAction(e:MouseEvent):void{
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerAction);
}
function onMseOutAction(e:MouseEvent):void{
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerAction);
    sq_mc.alpha = 1;
}
function timerAction(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    if (!blink){
        sq_mc.alpha = 1;
    } else{
        sq_mc.alpha = 0;
    }
    blink = !blink;
}
```

Mr.Allan, I have changed.

Comment: Never a good idea to compare Numbers. Floating point errors can result in alpha values being something like 0.00000001 and will fail the equality check. Not so much with the numbers 0 and 1 but try setting the alpha to 0.6 and then tracing the alpha value and you will end up with something like 0.59765625.

Comment: @allan: Thanks, and I have changed my codings.